# RewriteRule with trailing slash

Tags: apache-httpd

I need to redirect some link with or without trailing slashes:

`www.domain.con/foo`   → `www.domain.com/redirect` (working)
`www.domain.com/foo/` → `www.domain.com/redirect` (not working)

I tried this rule in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule (.*)/foo/$ http://www.domain.com/redirect$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

To redirect `www.domain.com/foo` or `www.domain.com/foo/` to `www.domain.com/redirect` you need to make the match on the trailing slash optional with a question mark (`/?`):

```
RewriteRule ^foo/?$ http://www.domain.com/redirect [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Same problem, don't work

Comment: To resolve partially i have make a 301 redirect that work without trailing slash `Redirect 301 /foo http://www.domain.com/redirect` but with trailing slash and RewriteRule i have a double `/` es. `http://www.domain.com/redirect//`

Comment: That's very odd.  I've just ran a test on an Amazon EC2 instance and it does work.  How are you testing?  I used `wget -O /dev/null --no-cache <url>` to make sure that my browser wasn't caching anything.  The above command will show the 301 redirect.

Comment: i tried to move `RewriteRule` from .htaccess to /etc/httpd/conf.d/myconf.conf inside `<Virtualhost>` directive and my original rules works (`RewriteRule (.*)/foo/$ http://www.domain.com/redirect$1 [L,R=301]`). It's possible that `RewriteRule` works only in a vitrualhost directive?

Comment: From the Apache documentation, `RewriteRule` works in server config, virtual host, directory, .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^foo/?$ http://www.domain.com/redirect [L,R=301]
```

This is a correct solution but will not carry the variable over, just a page to page. If you are having caching issues I recommend using https://httpstatus.io/ to verify the redirects as it doesn't seem to cache any of the redirect information. Also, testing using 302 instead of 301 will keep the browser from being stubborn about giving up the cached page location.